# How can I mimic an isometric perspective using square tiles?

Tags: javascript, tiles, tilemap, isometric, perspective

Can an isometric perspective be mimicked with traditional square tiles? Can't the effects of the 45-degree overhead view simply be "drawn in" to the square? How would this work?

Picture this: the tiles themselves are square (not diamond) but all objects placed on them (sprites, terrain objects like trees, buildings, etc) are drawn from isometric view as if they were on diamonds.

This might be a silly question to ask, but I'm having difficulty understanding isometric perspective.

Comment: Why don't you make a mockup in Paint/Photoshop and see for yourself? ;-)

Comment: I actually planned to to do that if I couldn't find the answer on Google but happened to not have access to photoshop right now :).

Comment: also, it would be hard to test the reprecussions using purely photoshop. what about how movement is affected on the x/y axis? i would really like someone with experience to comment on what I'm trying to do here. there must be good reasons why devs use diamond tiles and maps for isometric games.

Comment: @KromStern Was this comment sarcastic? Am I that much of an idiot for thinking that? I can't tell!

Comment: That was a constructive comment, because at the moment your question is still unclear.

Comment: Sure, you could add isometric sprites to square tiles. But since sprites are diamond shaped and the tiles aren't you're going to have a lot of "dead" space around your sprites, unless you position sprites in a way, that they can overlap more than one tile (but that kinda defeats the purpose of a tile-based game). Traditionally, the isometric sprites take up the whole tile, that's why tile and sprite have the same shape.

Comment: @bummzack That's sort of what I concluded based on my experiments in photoshop. See, the dead space isn't so much of a concern for me because non of the objects (like trees, buildings, cliffs, etc) on the terrain will not be part of the tiles, they will instead be sprites on top of the tiles, able to be placed anywhere on the tiles and even on multiple tiles (overlapping). Can you clarify what you mean by that "sort of defeats the purpose of a tile-based game"?  I know in RPG's movement is usually restricted to 1 unit, 1 tile. But I'm building an RTS and need tile-based for creating maps.

Comment: You might have a look to this answer i made here :  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/73874/20347

Comment: @GameAlchemist Wow, that is a seriously in-depth answer... your fiddle is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Would I be able to hire you for consulting on a project? Please skype me: cscott5288. Thanks!